# 18.04 LTS install failure with 'Couldn't get size' error

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

When trying to install Ubuntu 18.04, [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzHlM.jpg) appears with a 'Couldn't get size' error when I pick *Install Ubuntu* from the grub boot menu.

[image: 'Couldn't get size' error]

As you can see my boot menu, there is no option for any nomodeset anywhere. After 10 seconds, again I got the black screen!

[image: GRUB boot menu]

PC specs:

- [Asus Prime Z390-A](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z390-A/specifications/) motherboard
- Intel i7 9700k
- 2x16GB Corsair RGB Pro
- Nvidia RTX 2080Ti Asus OC11
- Samsung 970 Evo Plus 1 TB, NVMe, model [MZ-V7S1T0](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/970evoplus/)
- Samsung [860 Evo 500 GB] 2.5, model  MZ-76E500BW

Everything is up to date from BIOS settings to all firmware.
I would like to partition my M.2 (currently running Windows 10) and run Ubuntu as soon as possible, but I don't know how to do that. Aside from that, is my Samsung 860 Evo going to be ready to use in Ubuntu as a second drive?

Comment: Booting from and running on your 970 Evo Plus 1TB will be faster than booting from the 860 Evo 500 GB. Please click [edit] and advise which you wish to boot from and run on. Please also advise if the Evo 860 500 GB drive is an M.2 module or a 2.5" drive. Click [edit] and put that information in your question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead click [edit].

Comment: `Couldn't get size` is not an error. Your problem is with Nvidia drivers. Use `nomodeset` and then install drivers.

Comment: I can't procceed to Try Ubuntu without installing in order to be able to de-activate nomodeset ! I get the same black screen!

Comment: You boot with `nomodeset`, then install the system. Then boot the installed system with `nomodeset`, then install drivers, then remove `nomodeset`. The problem is that the default `nouveau` driver doesn't support your Nvidia card.

Answer (score 0):

One of your drive has a partition for a different OS which the installation routine cannot erase or shrink; you must take care of that yourself.

Please decide if you wish to boot from the 1 TB NVMe M.2 module or the 500 GB SATA-III drive. The former is faster.

Instead of choosing *Install Ubuntu* from the boot menu of [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) please choose *Try Ubuntu before you install it*. Ubuntu will then continue to boot.

When it completes booting, look at lower left, click on the 3x3 square of dots which shows available apps and choose [Disks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Disks).  All drives are listed on the left, and the drive you select will show detail about it at the right.

If you wish to preserve all or part of what's on the drive you want to install Ubuntu on and boot from, stop and exit from the Disks app and come back here for further instructions.

However, if you intend to have Ubuntu as the only operating system on this drive, erase all the partitions on it by clicking on each partition in turn and clicking on the - button before moving to the next partition.

When all have been erased, then close the Disks app. Then, [follow these instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.) to install Ubuntu.